# "This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN... enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations" What can I do?

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow using conda. When I test it, I get this performance:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

a = tf.constant([1, 2])
b = tf.constant([3, 4])
print(a + b)
```

#### Output

```
C:\Users\NHoracio\Miniconda3\envs\tesis\python.exe "D:/Dropbox/Codigos/Python3/TensorFlow test/test.py"
2.0.0
2019-12-25 12:13:37.613118: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145] This TensorFlow binary is optimized
with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance critical operations:
AVX AVX2

To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2019-12-25 12:13:37.621213: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115] Creating new thread pool with
default inter op setting: 8. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.

tf.Tensor([4 6], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

I know it can keep working in this way, and I am not sure if I am understanding that message. **I would like to know if I can improve the performance with the CPU or what I must do for that message?**

Configuration:
Windows 10 64b.
Intel i5 8250.
GF MX130
Python 3.7.4
PyCharm 2019.3.1
Conda 4.8.0
Tensorflow 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I updated tensorflow this morning and that particular error message was no longer there.  Here is the code I was running:

```
# smorgasbord of import statements scraped from random Internet sites
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.constraints import unit_norm
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import pandas as pd

# import os
# print(os.getcwd())

# establishing a single random seed for reproducibility of results
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

# load Bezdek Iris dataset
dataframe = pd.read_csv("BezdekIris.csv", header=None)

# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
dataset = dataframe.values
X = dataset[:, 0:3].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:, 4]

# create dummy indicator output variables to use in Keras
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = to_categorical(encoded_Y)

# cross-validation train/test methodology scraped from the Internet
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []
for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
    # create model (no idea what I am doing here at all...)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3, activation='relu',
                    kernel_constraint=unit_norm()))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=unit_norm()))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax', kernel_constraint=unit_norm()))

    # compile and evaluate model (no idea why these options work/if they do)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X[train], dummy_y[train], epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
    scores = model.evaluate(X[test], dummy_y[test], verbose=0)

    # display each validation fold's results
    print("%s:  %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
    cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)

# display overall results
print("%.2f%% (+/-%.2f%%)" % (np.mean(cvscores), np.std(cvscores)))
```

Comment: Of course, there is a new message in red text which I had not seen before...but at least it does not look serious and there are only two such messages displaying now.  Leaving my code alone and updating tensorflow is my default path forward from now on.